# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $x,y$ be two different points in it. Show that $B(x,r) \cap B(y,r) = \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $x,y$ be two different points in it. Show that $$B(x,r) \cap B(y,r) = \emptyset$$ when $r=\frac{d(x,y)}{2}$.

So the objective is to prove that the neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$ share no elements if $r=\frac{d(x,y)}{2}$. If I pick $a \in B(x,r)$ then I have that $d(a,x) < \frac{d(x,y)}{2}$ and similarly if $b \in B(y,r)$ then $d(b,y) <\frac{d(x,y)}{2}$. I'm wondering how I can use these inequalities to show this? The fact that $d$ is a metric in $X$ would imply also that the triangle inequality would be applicable here, but it doesn't seem to help. What can I do to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $a$ is in the intersection, $d(x,y)\leq d(x,a)+d(a,y)<2{{d(x,y)}\over 2}=d(x,y)$ contradiction